I have strange markings on my 2nd hand camera back display. Is that fixable?
I received a second hand Panasonic camera and have strange markings on the screen.


Can it be fixed? It hasn’t been dropped by me, wetted or anything that can do that.
And the eye scanner has a red light is that normal?

The stuff that you show on the images look like stress cracks on the screen. Especially the one on the "arrow down on stack" icon looks like some round object pressed into the screen too hard.
As you stated in the comments that the damage is new, I am afraid you broke your screen. Things like that can happen  even if something in your photo bag presses too much through the padding onto the screen. Touch screens especially can be a bit sensitive.
Unless the previous owner added a glass screen protector, in which case you could be lucky that it is only the protective glass, the screen is cracked and would need replacement unless you can live with the damage.
Whether that is economically viable depends heavily on the camera model and worth of the camera. If it is a newer model you will be able to get a replacement screen and a service provider capable of the fix.
Another option, as the damage is relatively minor, if to try adding a glass screen protector. You have a chance that the adhesive material will seep into the cracks, and seal that. This would make them less pronounced and keep the cracks sealed and somewhat stabilized.
Please be aware, if your camera has a touch screen, you will see the cracks becoming worse due to the pressure which will flex the glass and work the cracks.
Regarding the "eye scanner" - I am not sure which feature you are meaning: Do you mean the red focus-assist light on the front of the camera for dark situations? Yes, that is red on many cameras, white on some.
Or the eye sensor that detects if you are using the viewfinder? If you mean that, it could be that a small LED is used to support the eye detection in dark environments. As the camera resembles the LX-100 series, I had a glance in the manual, but the manual does not say anything regarding an LED there. Can you state the exact model of the camera? A red LED there could mean anything from film is recording, saving to SD card or to a support light for the eye sensor. As your screen is completely white, could it be that you pushed the film recording button?

My Panasonic G9 has an eye-sensor. It can be used to switch between monitor and view-finder. There is also a focus-mode named "Eye sensor AF" where the camera automatically adjusts the focus when the eye sensor is active.

The screen wasn’t like that when first got the camera, it was normal .

@ZebraFinch Then I am afraid, you broke you screen. Things like that can happen if something in photo bag presses too much through the padding and applies that pressure onto the screen. Especially touch screens can be a bit sensitive.

@AdrianHHH Good point. There is a red light near the viewfinder in one photo. I have included that.

"arrow down on stack" is commonly a compression level indicator.  HTH.

Also the screen isn’t touch screen!

Thank you for the answer I have noticed the cracks get a little kinda bigger it might be the charger to transfer photos that might be causing the problem which is on the back of the case and the front of the case that might be adding pressure
